# Are linear Hall Effect sensors concidered "benign" components for EMC testing?

Tags: emc, hall-effect

The EU's [EMC Directive](https://ec.europa.eu/docsroom/documents/33601) lists reasons a component/product can be considered "benign" and therefore is exempt compliance testing. One of these reasons follows:

> Equipment   containing   only   resistive   loads   without   any automatic  switching  device;  e.g.  simple  domestic  heaters  with no controls, thermostat, or fan;

Would a simple circuit board with linear hall effect sensors (like the [DRV5055](https://www.ti.com/product/DRV5055)) therefore be exempt (or for any of the other reasons mentioned in the document)?

Comment: These ICs do contain switching circuits. They alternate current direction through the Hall element at typical frequencies of ~MHz. As such they also contain clock generators etc... However, fully passive Hall elements can be also obtained. They have 4 pins such as the ancient KSY14. Maybe you can use such Hall elements.

Comment: @tobalt if you make that into an answer I'd happily accept it :)

Comment: thank you but I don't think that this is comprehensive enough for an answer. While I am certain that the DRV5055 would be subject to EMC testing, I have doubts whether the passive sensors would be indeed an exception. My feeling is 'yes', if your board is really just a breakout without any active electronics, but looks like Lundin has another opinion and I am no EMC expert.